# Error message when trying to retrieve data from external url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to retrieve JSON data from another site and then parse it however I get the error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Basingstoke&APPID=17d7c464b1b3c40e4c48297d750a9010

my code:

```
<% require 'json' %>
<% request_uri = 'api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' + @cityweather.city + "&APPID=17d7c464b1b3c40e4c48297d750a9010" %>
<% data = open(request_uri).read %>
<% weather = JSON.parse(data) %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `http://` to the beginning of your `request_uri` variable:

`<% request_uri = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=' + @cityweather.city + "&APPID=17d7c464b1b3c40e4c48297d750a9010" %>`